# How do I ask 'Which one?'

Tags: english-to-german

When asking 'Which one?' in German should I use

> Welches?

Or should I ask

> Welches mann?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you believe either one would be correct? Also, the answer depends on context.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Would you care to tell us your native language? Did you check a dictionary (which we kind of expect because we're no translation service) and what did you find? Problem is, that in German there is not *one* translation for" wich one" because German has three genders and we need context for an exact answer - or someone has to type a really extensive reply to cover all cases and eventualities.

Comment: *Three genders* and *4 cases*. Hence there's at least 3 times 4 solutions at this time. Please add some context to your question, such as if it is part of a bigger sentence/text and what your aim is

Comment: I really wonder how you came up with "Welches mann?". Whichever dictionary you're using, throw it away!

Comment: @Em1, I suppose that the translation of “one” as “man” has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the gender of the noun you refer to it can be welcher/welche/welches.

Comment: Or *welchen/welche/welches* or... - see dot_Sp0T's comment above.

Answer (score 0):

As the others said: We have three genders and four cases. So the ending of the word depends on the context. `Welches` might be the correct one for you. `Welches mann` is wrong in any case.

So these are examples for you:

## Männlich

### Nominativ

*Welcher* Mann hat dich angesehen? (Which man looked at you?)

### Genitiv

Dem Blick *welchen* Mannes warst du ausgesetzt? (Whose mans look have you been exposed to?)

### Dativ

*Welchem* Mann hast du einen Blick zugeworfen? (Which man did you dart a look at?)

### Akkusativ

*Welchen* Mann hast du angesehen? (Which man did you look at?)

## Weiblich

### Nominativ

*Welche* Frau hat dich angesehen? (Which woman looked at you?)

### Genitiv

Dem Blick *welcher* Frau warst du ausgesetzt? (Whose womans look have you been exposed to?)

### Dativ

*Welcher* Frau hast du einen Blick zugeworfen? (Which woman did you dart a look at?)

### Akkusativ

*Welche* Frau hast du angesehen? (Which woman did you look at?)

## Neutral

### Nominativ

*Welches* Kind hat dich angesehen? (Which child looked at you?)

### Genitiv

Dem Blick *welchen* Kindes warst du ausgesetzt? (Whose childs look have you been exposed to?)

### Dativ

*Welchem* Kind hast du einen Blick zugeworfen? (Which child did you dart a look at?)

### Akkusativ

*Welches* Kind hast du angesehen? (Which child did you look at?)

So according to what you want to ask, your `Which one` can be translated to `Welcher, Welchem, Welchen, Welche` or `Welches`. For example if someone tells you "Ich habe eine Frau angesehen", you would ask "Welche?". But if someone tells you "Ich habe ein Auto gefahren" you would ask "Welches?".

It took me a while to find sentences in the genitive form. You can't ask "Which one?" for them. If someone tells you "Ich war dem Blick eines Mannes ausgesetzt?" you will ask "Wessen?" (or you make it easier for you and say "Wer hat dich angeguckt?)

Comment: You have answered the wrong question. What about the “one”?

Comment: There is no word you append to "Welche/r/s/m" when you are asking "Which one?". Nobody would say "Welcher einer" or something like that.

Comment: And that was the question, as I understand it. Although I now see that you last sentence addresses it.

Comment: But your genitive case examples do not really fit in.

Comment: Oh, you can! ;) "Welch einen Wagen fährst du?" "Welch eine Frau hast du geheiratet?" "Welch ein Mann!" – I'm just trolling. I'm not asking to address this in your answer.

Comment: On a bit more serious note: A reference to a table would have been sufficient enough anyway. For example: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/welcher

Comment: You can't really translate "Which one?" to a genitive sentence (at least i can't find a sentence that makes sense). I just wanted them to be in my answer to have a sentence for each case. @Em1: Your examples aren't genitive either. The website you linked says that there are genitive forms for "welcher". I really had a hard time finding sentences with that, but i will add that to my answer.

Comment: @Dorian I didn't intend to refer to the genitive form. I couldn't come up with an example myself. The "Welch ein" examples were a comment on your note that nobody would say "welcher einer"; the reference to wiktionary for the mere sake of clarity. However, isn't it "dem Blick welches Kindes" and "dem Blick welches Mannes"?

Comment: @Em1: Sorry, I misunderstood that :) I think you can use both "dem Blick *welches* Mannes" or "dem Blick *welchen* Mannes". Your table refers to both of them, too. Which one of them sounds better seems to be a regional thing. Both of them are very uncommon, at least i don't hear sentences like that very often.

Comment: @Dorian, you are right, but the phrase corresponding to “Which one's?” would have fit into your list. I see you have modified your answer, thanks!